# scenekit screenshot with snapshot() methods

Tags: ios, screenshot, scenekit, snapshot

I am using scenekit in one of my games. I make a screenshot with `snapshot()` method of SCNSceneView class. I ran the Time Profiler and a wast amount of time was spent with this method. Can you provide me with some info on how good approach is to take screenshots with `snapshot()` and if other methods should be used instead?

Comment: snapshot does not seem to take a lot of time in my app. Do you have ` isJitteringEnabled` turned on? This might cause it to wait.